# How to make a div's height equal to the page height?

Tags: html, css

I've been searching around for about an hour now, and I can't seem to figure this out: How do I make the height of a  equal to not the window height, but the page height? I'm Making a website, and I want to have little decorations that span the whole side-margin. However, I've been trying to set the height of  and  and using in inherit, using inherit by itself, and setting the height to 100%, but all of them ended up yielding:
1. No change, or
2. No Height whatsoever.
Could someone give a way to do this?

Comment: What your tried can you share link or demo

Comment: Talk is cheap...show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

vh is the height relative to the viewport
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp